# The comment form is displayed incorrectly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-comments

I am making comments on django on this video

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmFkND-scpY`

when the author in the middle of the video showed what he had done, he showed this (this is how it should be)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSHiM.png)

but for some reason it turned out like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmTqp.png)

class Comment in **models.py**

```
    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Some String")
        body = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'body']
```

def detail in **views.py**

```
def detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'myblog/templates/post_detail.html', context)
```

**post_detail.py**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post-entry">
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">+ Edit Blog Post</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk %}">+ Delete Blog Post</a></p>
    <img src="{{ post.header_image.url|default_if_none:'#' }}">


    {{ post.body|urlize }}


    {% for comm in post.commentpost_set.all%}
        {{ comm.user }} <br>
        {{ comm.text }} <br><br>
    {% endfor %}

    <article class="content">

        <br><hr>
        <h2>Add a comment</h2>

        <form method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_table }}

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

if necessary, tell me, I'll throw off the files completely, I just didn't want to clog the question with a lot of code
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't redefine `form` (or perhaps `context`) somewhere in your `detail` view? Asking because of the last statement you leave in the question.

Comment: sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean, I'm new to python and django